# navigation property is not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, entity-framework-4

I am using a *objectDataSource* to populate a *gridview*. I have 2 simple classes :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I also have

```
public class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

}
```

now in my EmployeeRepository class i have

```
public List<Department> GetDepartments()
{
    EmployeeDBContext employeeDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
    return employeeDBContext.Departments.Include("Employees").ToList();
}
```

Even though I have added  *.Include("Employees")*, the employees are missing in *gridview*. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure you are getting an empty list or the binding to the datasource is not working? you must use the include because the lazy loading is not working without virtual

Comment: @BassamAlugili im not getting empty list for the whole thing. i get result but the data from employee table is missing!!

Comment: try with lazy loading just change this line public virual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

Comment: the problem is solve or not?

Comment: Nop...I'm still getting the same result

Comment: you are using a very old version 4? normally what you are doing is very basic. just do the same test with EF 6.x.x . one thing is still important use the  DbContext always withing using( var myDbContext = new DbContext()) dbContext is disposable

Comment: I'm actually using 6.0. okay ...let me show you this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbH-rqMl8cE&index=3&list=PL6n9fhu94yhUPBSX-E2aJCnCR3-_6zBZx . if you watch the last 30 sec, you would see what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: now if i add .Include("Employees") or not ...my result is the same @BassamAlugili

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to have a foreign key *(DepartmentId)* inside Employee class. *I do not know how the video got away with that.*

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; } <=====
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
           ^^^^^^^
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

public partial class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Optional, but good practice to have the mapping here. 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Employee)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Department)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartmentId);
    }
}
```

*- OR -*

Add **DepartmentId** property and **[ForeignKey]** data annotation to Department.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }    
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; } <=== 

    // Optional, but good practice to have this data annotation attribute. 
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")] <=== 
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

*FYI: You want to use virtual, in case someone wants to use lazy loading in the future.*

Comment: wht you think he need to configure extra the entity  with fluent API? he has one-to-many releshinship in code first.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this

`return employeeDBContext.Departments.Include(x =>x.Employees ).ToList();` ?